# Angular 8.2.4: What is the cause to the error: Unknown browser query during ng build

Tags: angular

I ran: ng build and got the following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred: [BABEL] D:\zvi_vered\git\ELTA_34\dist\Elta\main-es2015.js: Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's`. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query. (While processing: "D:\zvi_vered\git\ELTA_34\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js")
>   See "C:\Users\990598\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-xSoBnK\angular-errors.log" for further details.

The file angular-errors.log contains:

> [error] BrowserslistError: [BABEL] D:\zvi_vered\git\ELTA_34\dist\Elta\runtime-es2015.js: Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's`. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query. (While processing: "D:\zvi_vered\git\ELTA_34\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js")
>       at unknownQuery (D:\zvi_vered\git\ELTA_34\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:204:10)
>       at D:\zvi_vered\git\ELTA_34\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:296:11
>       at Array.reduce ()
>       at resolve (D:\zvi_vered\git\ELTA_34\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:237:18)
>       at browserslist (D:\zvi_vered\git\ELTA_34\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:361:16)
>       at getTargets (D:\zvi_vered\git\ELTA_34\node_modules@babel\preset-env\lib\targets-parser.js:204:50)
>       at _default (D:\zvi_vered\git\ELTA_34\node_modules@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js:132:46)
>       at D:\zvi_vered\git\ELTA_34\node_modules@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:19:12
>       at loadDescriptor (D:\zvi_vered\git\ELTA_34\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:165:14)
>       at cachedFunction (D:\zvi_vered\git\ELTA_34\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\caching.js:33:19)
>       at loadPresetDescriptor (D:\zvi_vered\git\ELTA_34\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:235:63)
>       at config.presets.reduce (D:\zvi_vered\git\ELTA_34\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:77:21)
>       at Array.reduce ()
>       at recurseDescriptors (D:\zvi_vered\git\ELTA_34\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:74:38)
>       at loadFullConfig (D:\zvi_vered\git\ELTA_34\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:108:6)
>       at process.nextTick (D:\zvi_vered\git\ELTA_34\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transform.js:28:33)

Can you please help ?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: I erased the contents of the file browserlist. I do not need support in any browser but chrome.